# Why WCF SoapFault responses are encrypted in some situations?

Tags: wcf, web-services, soapfault

I am creating a WCF webservice whose requests/responses are supposed to be signed only.
For this, on ServiceContract attribute I have set

```
ProtectionLevel = ProtectionLevel.Sign
```

That works ok.

Due to requirements some SoapFaults are supposed to be thrown from service; two types of SoapFaults:

- related to application
- related to WS-Addressing (e.g. MessageID is missing)

For this I am using the normal of approach of dealing with SoafFaults: create an IErrorHandler in which a Message instance is created with MessageFault.CreateFault.

Almost all the returned SoapFaults are not encrypted (which is ok for me),
my question is why the ones with action="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/fault" or "http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/soap/fault" are encrypted?

Comment: how do you know it is encrypted? can you provide a sample response?

Comment: I know is encrypted because I view it with SvcTraceViewer (on client side).

Comment: @csg have you found out why? I am having the exact same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347791.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.faultcontractattribute.aspx. 
It states that

> If you select a binding that enables security and you do not set the
>   ProtectionLevel property anywhere on the contract, all application
>   data will be encrypted and signed.

I guess that the build in types by default use this behaviour. You can verify this by looking at which exception is actually thrown.

Comment: The protection level is set at the contract level with: [ServiceContract(ProtectionLevel = ProtectionLevel.Sign)]